# Definitely not suspicious

Tags: word, cipher

This unsuspicious ... post - has just a bunch of random letters.

No secret words, no silly ciphers, nothing.

Nothing to see here. Goodbye.

**Urgent secret message: Go to another question**

*ahem, what are you still doing here?*

> aeioubdfhjstvngclmrykpqwz (What? Don't look!)

Haha! You can't see it.

Can everyone apart somewhere? Another riddle?

***No no no! Don't look at the second one!***

> 1. suufbudyeliley. fyezeled, sumihv, guzhogfrcgeri 2. jiccuazug. -tvinin

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: It's a message (second one). groups of 5 as a hint.

Comment: letter X missing in first clue.. what is question here?

Comment: what's the hidden message?

Comment: x is so "groups of five"

Comment: The puzzle looks less fun now :-( You're just telling us the solution method, without that intriguing initial text.

Comment: oh. sorry. i'll change back to the original

Comment: I want to scream because draw an award says cesear cipher and there so much stuff about this puzzle wherever you post like on your profile page and I don't know where to start or anything.

Comment: Start at the first hidden bar. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Plaintext

> 1. goodjobracecar  drawacab  goleft  nowfindmyname 2. heyyouwon. -stevev

## Cipher Method

> The alphabet is written in a 5x5 square. Each letter of the plaintext is replaced with the letter directly to its right in the alphabet square, wrapping around when the letter is found at the right edge of the square. To decipher, take the letter directly to the left.
>
> ```
>     aeiou
>     bdfhj
>     stvng
>     clmry
>     kpqwz
>
> 1. suufbudyeliley. fyezeled, sumihv, guzhogfrcgeri 2. jiccuazug. -tvinin
> 1. GOODJOBRACECAR. DRAWACAB, GOLEFT, NOWFINDMYNAME 2. HEYYOUWON. -STEVEV
> ```

> This is a simple substitution, but the word choice is unusual enough that [Quipquip](https://quipqiup.com/) struggles to solve it automatically. The false word spaces were a nice touch, too. My break-in was... basically a lucky guess, after noticing that the vowels are already in the right place, so the cipher must be replacing vowels with other vowels.