# 4824 Draw an award 4284

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, lateral-thinking

After you finished the last one with a ceasar cipher: [ [Definitely not suspicious](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69913/definitely-not-suspicious) ]

I realize that you guys cannot be distracted.

So, I will tell you the answer, right here.

> Hey, look! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jk71bPz5VLo

$Phew!$

While everyone's trying to find a hidden message in that video,

> I can now safely enter some secret info for a secret word!

Haha! People will think it's random text anyway.

1.

> tba.n.banaao.annot.

2.

> ii.tt.i.is.si.i.

3.

> amnc.a.aaniic.

4.

> bmle.kekare.wmr.w.abl.raraasisae.

Comment: Please don't waste your time watching through that probably red herring.

Comment: Yes, I was 6 seconds through when I thought this was a waste of time

Comment: I WATCHED THE ENTIRE THING AND MY HEAD IS FILLED WITH KNOWLEDGE I LITERALLY CANT LEARN ANYTHING ELSE AFTER THIS.

Comment: Why did you watch "The Most Boring Video Ever!!!"?

Comment: @RohitJose Better question: how did you manage to watch the whole video???

Comment: @Alto I THOUGHT THERE WAS ACTUALLY SOMETHING IN THERE

Comment: @practiced_liar I need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint given in [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72337/an-alternate-answer)

> I tried to make palindromes out of the 4 pieces of text and got:

1.

> not a banana baton

2.

> it is I is it I

3.

> cain a maniac

4.

> elba kramer saw I was remarkable?

Finally

> Taking the first (or last letters) of each of the 4 gives NICE.

Video is probably a red herring

Comment: What's number 4? You're going good, by the way. Also, I would've thought people would see the palindrome in the title, and think, OH, palindromes, but, oh well.

Comment: Also, #2 is, " Is it I? It is I! ", but the answer would still be the same.

Comment: I had actually not seen this question till I saw the hint in the other puzzle. And then I noticed the palindrome in the title as well :P Working on the 4th one...

Comment: You're so close! Almost! Look at those palindromes, something about them....

Comment: Am I closer @Alto?

Comment: Nice! You win!!

Comment: Yay! This was a 'nice' puzzle :D