# An alternate answer

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

**Really rare report!**

Today, Todd texted this:

> ♦☼ ↓☼§ ♂♫☼↨ ¶◘♣ ☺♫‼○↨♣↕ ♠☼↕ ◄§♣‼¶♥○☼♫ ‼○↑ ☼♫ ¶◘♣ ♪☺¶◘ ◘☼♪♣↨☼♣↕♂? ○ ♥☺♫'¶ ♠○•§↕♣ ○¶ ☼§¶.

Although, having solved it, I decided it's too easy and decided to give some red herrings.

Now nobody will find the secret word! Mwahahahahahaha!

***Hey! Look down there!***

> Hey, have you seen how much information wikipedia has on puzzles? Check it out!

Man, I hope no one notices how to solve [4824 Draw an award 4284](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71347/4824-draw-an-award-4284)
with palindromes.

That would be *so unfortunate.*

> Hint - A word in this puzzle's title is key.
>
> Hint #2 - Take the hints literally. Think about the first hint carefully.
>
> Hint #3 - Why did I put lateral-thinking as a tag?

Comment: The key might be alternate and the text might be red herring because alternate

Comment: Yeah sure. Go ahead. It probably could be a red herring. Definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the answer

> ICE?
>
>  Based on the hints, the key is literally the key. So, by converting the text from alternate code, we get:
>  DO YOU KNOW THE ANSIWER FOR QUESTCION SIX ON THE MATH HOMEWOERK? I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT.